# Unknown error when using .NET 4.0 with dll

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, dllimport

c++ code is

```
MSIPC_SDK LONG __stdcall Ms_IpcClient_CaptureImage(LONG nUserId, char *sFilePath, 
    int nPathLen, const char *sDiskPath = NULL);//sDiskPath example: "C: \\".
```

Affect: Take a snapshoot

Parameters remark:

- `LONG nUserId`: Ms_Ipc_Login()//Return value after login successfully
- `char *sFilePath`: //destination for saving the recording files
- `int nPathLen`: //the length of the path
- `const char *sDiskPath = NULL`: //which disk to be saved

my c# code is:

```
[DllImport("MsIpcSDK", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, 
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int Ms_IpcClient_CaptureImage(
    int lUserID, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    string sFilePath, 
    int nPathLen,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    string sDiskPath
);
```

and using is method:

```
var ret = Ms_IpcClient_CaptureImage(loginID, "C:\\a.bmp", 10000, "C:\\");
```

It is working in .Net Framework 2 but does not work in .Net Framework 4.
How can I fix it in .Net Framework 4?

Comment: Define "not working". What doesn't work? You get a compile error? What kind of error?

Comment: in .net 4 when using method show stopped working (a problem caused program to stop working correctly) and close program

Comment: Did you try to debug your program to see where exactly it fails? Did you make sure that your parameters are properly passed to the function? Is LoginID valid? did you try `@"C:\a.tmp"` instead of `"C:\\a.tmp"`? Did you try to use `CharSet = CharSet.Default`?

Comment: @LightBulb `@"C:\a.tmp" == "C:\\a.tmp"` and `CharSet = CharSet.Default` is equivalent to `CharSet.Ansi` on Windows, and in any case each text parameter has `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)` so the value of `CharSet` is in fact irrelevant. You seem to be guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sFilePath` is used to pass a string from callee to caller. That's why the type is `char*` rather than `const char*`, and that's why there is a parameter for buffer length. That means you need to use `StringBuilder` rather than `string`. The p/invoke should be:

```
[DllImport("MsIpcSDK", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, 
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int Ms_IpcClient_CaptureImage(
    int lUserID, 
    StringBuilder sFilePath, 
    int nPathLen,
    string sDiskPath
);
```

And the call should be:

```
var filePath = new StringBuilder(260);
var ret = Ms_IpcClient_CaptureImage(loginID, filePath, filePath.Capacity, "C:\\");
```

Your code has always been wrong and you've just been getting away with it up until now. The fact that you passed a made up buffer length value of `10000` should have set the alarm bells ringing!